# Aerospike Aql WARN AEROSPIKE_ERR_TIMEOUT

Tags: aerospike

I am running aerospike 3.6.0 community eddition on ubuntu12.04 when I type aql it start prompting below WARN due to which I am not able to run any query.

```
~/Downloads/aerospike-server-community-3.6.0-ubuntu12.04$ aql
2015-09-08 11:57:29 WARN AEROSPIKE_ERR_TIMEOUT 
2015-09-08 11:57:30 WARN AEROSPIKE_ERR_TIMEOUT 
Aerospike Query
Copyright 2013-2015 Aerospike. All rights reserved.

aql> 2015-09-08 11:57:31 WARN AEROSPIKE_ERR_TIMEOUT 
2015-09-08 11:57:32 WARN AEROSPIKE_ERR_TIMEOUT 
2015-09-08 11:57:34 WARN AEROSPIKE_ERR_TIMEOUT 
2015-09-08 11:57:35 WARN AEROSPIKE_ERR_TIMEOUT 
2015-09-08 11:57:37 WARN AEROSPIKE_ERR_TIMEOUT 
2015-09-08 11:57:38 WARN AEROSPIKE_ERR_TIMEOUT
```

How can I stop warning?

Comment: please can you post output from asinfo -v services as this will tell us whether the cluster is seeding properly.  Also would be helpful if you test with the -h flag to AQL to specify the server.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Is your server actually running on localhost port 3000? Those are the defaults for `aql`. Something is running there that aql is trying and failing to connect to.